# pass textbox string to custom control using application properties

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

If I use this to pass a string **from** my mainwindow to my customcontrol, how would I then capture it in my custom control?

```
    private void btnGeneral_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string myText = (string)Application.Current.Properties[textBox1.Text];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how you do it:

```
//To Set:    
App.Current.Properties["TextBoxString"] = textBox1.Text;
//To Get:
string myProperty = (string) App.Current.Properties["TextBoxString"];
```

Check out this article for [Accessing the Application object in a WPF application](http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2006/09/07/accessing-the-application-object-in-a-wpf-application/)

Comment: but if I put `App.Current.Properties["TextBoxString"] = textBox1.Text;`
in my button on my mainwindow page when i place string `myProperty = App.Current.Properties["TextBoxString"];` in my custom control it says cannot implicitly convert object to string?

Comment: @KirstyWhite just edited the answer, you need to cast it to string before assigning it to myProperty